# Excel Macro Find Replace All Files in Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I want to implement this code to all my excel Files (close to 100) store in below folder.

I was searching for code, but unable to get the right one. can anyone please help me on this.

Path : "D:\Files"

```
Cells.Replace What:=" (Task Complete)", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

- Step 1 : Excel Macro Open Files
- Step 2: Run the Code
- Step 3: Close the Excel
- Step 4: Open Next Excel Sheet.
- Step 5: Step 1 to 3 and so on Till last file.

Comment: If you type your steps in google, you can get a fair idea on what needs to be done

Comment: I have already searched for it, but didn't get a fair idea. If you know the steps and code. and can share with me. That would be great.

Comment: `I have already searched for it, but didn't get a fair idea. If you know the steps and code. and can share with me. That would be great. – Gyan Chand 12 secs ago` Somehow I do not believe you :(. What do you get when you type `Excel Macro Open Files` in Google?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0PeXcAVaUM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5YgkvnTBfk I tried to check these videos, but didn't get fair idea how to change per my folder. I am not a tech guy. Just doing this task manually by opening each file. someone told me it could be done in Macro in a easy way. So looking for help. If you can, that would be great. IF not no prob.

Comment: Am done with 20 files till now.

Comment: I don't think you really understand... :)  Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for codes. You have to really put in efforts and show what have you tried and then we help you. If you want someone to give you the code in the platter then I recommend visiting Freelancer.Com

Answer (score -1):

The following assumes the workbook containing this code is in the same folder as the workbooks to be changed.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TaskCompleteReplace()
Dim lobjThisWorkBook As Workbook
Dim lobjOtherWorkbook As Workbook
Dim lobjWorksheet As Worksheet

Dim lstrFileSpec As String

Set lobjThisWorkBook = ThisWorkbook

lstrFileSpec = Dir(lobjThisWorkBook.Path + "\*.xls")
Do While Len(lstrFileSpec) > 0
    If InStr(lstrFileSpec, lobjThisWorkBook.Name) = 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open lobjThisWorkBook.Path + "\" + lstrFileSpec
        'Active workbook is now lstrFileSpec
        Set lobjOtherWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each lobjWorksheet In lobjOtherWorkbook.Sheets
            Cells.Replace What:=" (Task Complete)", Replacement:="Test Replaced", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set lobjWorksheet = Nothing
        lobjOtherWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        lobjThisWorkBook.Activate
        Set lobjOtherWorkbook = Nothing
    End If
    lstrFileSpec = Dir
Loop

Set lobjThisWorkBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: -- For setting a wrong trend in stackoverflow. See my last comment under OP's post

Comment: Thanks for your effort. If I go to my freelancer, my boss will fire me. So will try to learn the macros to make my life easy.